# How to select a range of two dates with Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, range

I have two datepicker boxes:

```
$('.datepicker1').datepicker();
$('.datepicker2').datepicker();
```

Assume that the **datepicker1 = 10/02/2016** and the **datepicker2 = 15/02/2016**.

How can I make a conditional statement that looks something like: "if the two dates are in the range between **01/01/2016** and **01/03/2016**, do something..."? How can I set this range?

I need to do different calculations based on this range with the two dates picked up.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#dt1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var date2 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
            $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', date2);
            //sets minDate to dt1 date + 1
            $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
        }
    });
    $('#dt2').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        onClose: function () {
            var dt1 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
            var dt2 = $('#dt2').datepicker('getDate');
            //check to prevent a user from entering a date below date of dt1
            if (dt2 <= dt1) {
                var minDate = $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't do the trick. I know how to get the two dates from the two datepicker boxes. The question is: after having picked up the two dates, how can I put them in a range that says: "if the two dates picked up are in a range that starts form this date (for example: 01/01/2016)  and finishes to another date (for example: 01/03./2016), do something"? I hope this clarifies :)